# Microsoft Sync framework, filtering based on many tables (joins ..)

Tags: c#, .net, synchronization

I am currently testing sync framework.

I have just wanted to synchronize data from a table based on criteria from other tables.
I have managed to do this following JuneT post on:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/synclab/thread/f8516d4d-2352-468f-82e3-b06f18effaaa

The problem is that this solution is extremaly slow ...
It seems to me that "item in (select ...)" construction is executed for every row in source table ..

There is also an option to modify table_selectchanges but It could be easily broken by recreating database's scope synchronization infrastructure.

Are there other solution for such task?

Thanks